# What does eslint mean by "commonjs" global variables?

Tags: eslint, commonjs, eslintrc

I'm having trouble understanding that part of the documentation.

[image]

What does eslint mean by "CommonJS global variables"? What those would be?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS

Comment: @tkausl Thanks. Could you give examples of what those globals would be? Is `require` one of them? What would be the others?